# rails activerecord polymorphic has_many to has_many get value from through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

My model relations look like this:

```
Firm:
has_many :taggings, as: taggable
has_many :articles, through: taggings

Person:
belongs_to :firm
has_many :taggings, as: taggable
has_many :articles, through: taggings

Tagging:
belongs_to :article
belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true

Article:
has_many :taggings
has_many :persons, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Person'
has_many :firms, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Firm'
```

A person belongs to a firm. A firm or person acts as a tag for an article, each article has many firms, and each firm/person has many Articles.
Basically everything works fine, but i have a Problem accessing a value from the Tagging table.
The Tagging table has a Field user, for storing who added this tagging.

I could of course get the value for each article/firm by doing

```
Tagging.find_by(article_id: article.id, tagging_id: firm.id, tagging_type: 'Firm')
```

and then create a new array and so on for displaying the data in my view, but this looks really ugly. Does anybody know a "rails way" for accessing the data in the "through table"?